# Converting code using generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics, optimization

I've following code that uses the passed `Object` and acts on it after determining its type. My question is that if I convert it to use generics, will I get any performance advantage since I'd still have to determine the type of T before I act upon it? Will I save ticks on boxing/unboxing?

```
private void BindOptionFields(Object obj, String selectedValue, int dataLanguageID)
    {
        String typ = obj.GetType().Name;
        switch(typ.ToLower()) 
        {
            case "ratingscaleitem":
                SetRatingScale((Common.RatingScaleItem)obj, dataLanguageID, selectedValue);
                break;
            case "taskstatus":
                text = ((TaskStatus)obj).TaskName;
                optionValue = ((TaskStatus)obj).StateID.ToString();  
                break;
            case "planlite":
                text =  ((XYZ.ABC.PlanLite)obj).PlanName;
                optionValue = ((XYZ.ABC.PlanLite)obj).Id.ToString();
                break;
            case "datarow":
                text =  ((DataRow)obj)["TextColumn"].ToString();
                optionValue = ((DataRow)obj)["KeyColumn"].ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (optionValue == selectedValue)
        {
            selected = true;
        }
    }
```

---

**Note:** I've 3 constructors in my class that receive an ArrayList of 20 different types (similar types in ArrayList for a particular call). I loop through the arraylist and call this `BindOptionFields()` so if I've to write overloaded methods, I'll have to overload my constructors for 20 cases each. Can someone suggest a less tedious solution that would be fast as well?

Comment: I think your best choice would be to split that method into 4 methods that take in specific types instead of an `object`.

Comment: If it helps, I had 20 odd types being provided in my actual code. So writing 20 functions with different signatures is my only option for performance improvement, right?

Comment: Generics won't get you anywhere. You'd be far better off using standard OOP practices, some form of polymorphism. This reads like 1970s C code.

Comment: Well, it'd be more readable than one giant switch statement. Having a lot of small, well-defined methods isn't a bad thing. With that many options, though, I agree with the suggestions of polymorphism and/or a common interface.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding generics.

If you convert this method to a generic method, the caller will need to specify the generic parameter at *compile-time*.
At that point, you can just use a normal set of overloaded methods.

Answer (score 2):

Would it not be better to add a BindOptionField method (perhaps as part of an Interface e.g. IOptionFieldBindable) to the types you're switching on here?

The TaskStatus, PlanLite, and DataRow Types are good candidates particularly, since they're each providing a different way to set the same two values. That way, you could just call

```
(obj as IOptionFieldBindable).BindOptionField(text, optionValue);
```

Your solution would also be less [Stringly Typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2444303#2444303) :)

Comment: Your solution looks good to me. But in some cases it pass DictionaryItem, DataRow etc... not sure how I'd extend those w/o writing too much code?

Comment: Well right now you've got 20 different cases in the if, then you'd have 20 methods which would be pretty much identical to the code in the switch. Apart from that I'd also really recommend getting rid of the Strings and using enums for that.